# How to ignore/exclude a url pattern in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to spring security and unable to find the correct answer on how to ignore a url patter from spring security in web.xml

currently in web.xml file i have the following config

```
web.xml -

    <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

and now I want to ignore a particular url with "/test"  can I do this using web.xml here if not what are all the possible solutions.

Comment: Hi, you can extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, override the protected void configure(HttpSecurity http), and do http
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/test/**").permitAll()

Comment: I tried that but didn't worked, we ae overriding couple of configure methods one is for AuthenticationManagerBuilder and second is for HttoSecurity, bcz of that it is not working, I even tried to over ride configure method websecurity by calling web.ignoring().antMatches("/") that one also didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to found the solution after lot of research :

I added below security constraint in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name>
    <description>Matches a few special pages.</description>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

and added below in Java config class:

```
@override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
      http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```